# JUnit Hamcrest assertion

Tags: java, junit, junit4, hamcrest

Is there a Hamcrest `Matcher` that cleanly lets me assert that the result of a method, that returns a `Collection` of objects, has at least one object that contains a property with certain value?

**For example:**

```
class Person {
   private String name;
}
```

The method under test returns a collection of `Person`.
I need to assert that at least one Person is called Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to create a [`Matcher`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html) that can match a `Person`'s name. Then, you could use hamcrest's [`CoreMatchers#hasItem`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#hasItem(org.hamcrest.Matcher)) to check if a `Collection` has an item this mathcer matches.

Personally, I like to declare such matchers anonymously in `static` methods as a sort of syntactic sugaring:

```
public class PersonTest {

    /** Syntactic sugaring for having a hasName matcher method */
    public static Matcher<Person> hasName(final String name) {
        return new BaseMatcher<Person>() {
            public boolean matches(Object o) {
               return  ((Person) o).getName().equals(name);
            }

            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Person should have the name ")
                           .appendValue(name);
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testPeople() {
        List<Person> people = 
            Arrays.asList(new Person("Steve"), new Person("Peter"));

        assertThat(people, hasItem(hasName("Peter")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks!

Comment: You may even use the `hasProperty` matcher in order to avoid writing a `hasName` matcher: `assertThat(people, hasItem(hasProperty("name", equalTo("Peter"))));`